# How to install package without root?

Tags: installation, package, root, dpkg

I have no root access on a ubuntu server. I would like to install mergerfs but I can not find anyway of doing this.

I have permission to install this software but the system administrator can not help me with the process.

When looking up this I have seen a lot of solutions but I cant get most to work or I can not understand them fully.

Fakeroot is installed on the system if this could be used? I did try copying `/var/lib` from a local machine to the home directory on the server and  downloading the `.deb` file from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/cosmic/amd64/mergerfs/2.21.0-1 then using both these commands:

```
fakeroot --lib /lib/ -- dpkg -i mergerfs/mergerfs_2.21.0-1_amd64.deb
fakeroot --lib /lib/ -- apt-get install mergerfs
```

I get output:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib/' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot read file data): ignored.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I have also tried:

```
dpkg -i mergerfs/mergerfs_2.21.0-1_amd64.deb --force-not-root --root=$HOME
```

which returned:

```
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

I came across this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access

Where I found:

> Finally, you could use the apt-get source command to fetch the source
>   of the package and configure it to install locally. Usually this looks
>   something like

```
apt-get source package
cd package
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

> The disadvantage to this approach is that you need the development
>   environment available for this approach to work at all, and you might
>   find yourself compiling dozens of packages in order to resolve all the
>   dependencies.

I did try this but the command line returned:

```
cant find ./configure
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.